# How am I supposed to deploy an ASP.NET 4 MVC website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

What's the recommended way to deploy a website created with ASP.NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010?

I've previously always added a web setup project to my solution, and used that to create an MSI, even for small applications.

But when I build a web setup project in VS2010 it kind of works but some stuff still seems broken:
1. I need to turn on IIS 6 Compatibility on a Win 2008 R2 box to get the msi to run.
2. The msi includes web.config, web.debug.config, and web.release.config. I thought VS's web.config transformations was supposed to take care of that.

-Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at using [MSDeploy](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2008/01/22/welcome-to-the-web-deployment-team-blog.aspx), which packages up all your files and configuration settings into a zip file that can then be imported into IIS 7.

Scott Hanselman had a great presentation that shows [how to use MSDeploy](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT14).